# Open file without specifying exact location

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, vim, filesystems

Say I have a file in some obscure directory that I want to open and edit. I don't want to do something like this...

`vim ~/foo/bar/blah/doh/ugh.txt`

I'd rather be able to say find this file and open it. I know there are commands like `locate` and `find` to find a file or directory, but I'm not sure whether these can (or even should) be utilized in what I'm trying to do. Basically, what is the simplest way to open a file with a program w/o specifying its exact location? (In cases where there isn't another file with the same name in the entire system, and cases where there are multiple).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will open *all* the files (potentially many) with that name that have been added to the database the last time `updatedb` was run (typically daily). This means files created since that time will not be found.

```
vim $(locate ugh.txt)
```

Unless you supply a starting directory to `find`, using it may be very slow. It may still be too slow even with a starting directory if there are a lot of files below it. The same warning regarding large numbers of files applies.

```
vim $(find /pathto/startdir -name 'ugh.txt' -type f)
```

Either of these could be turned into a function to reduce typing:

```
viml () { vim $(locate "$@"); }
```

Then use it like this:

```
viml ugh.txt
```

Comment: I was writing up `find . -name \*foo\* -print0 | xargs -0 sh -c 'vim </dev/tty "$@"' -` (which handles spaces, etc. in filenames), but since you wrote this, I will desist.

Comment: Your function will likely completely break using any non-file arguments to vim

Comment: @Daenyth: There's no question of that. The intention is that this is a convenience function for a particular purpose rather than a universal wrapper for `vim`. It could easily be made more robust if that were needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this : This helpful command lets you open only files that match a certain condition - in a directory and all it's subdirectories.

```
vi `grep -rl 'example.js' *
```

or you can see the [original reference](http://www.tipstrs.com/tip/2231/Open-a-list-of-files-in-vim-from-a-grep-command-%28linux%29)

Comment: That's based on the contents of the files rather than the filenames.

Comment: it also appears to be missing a trailing backtick...

Comment: @Dennis: ya you right I did't consider this.

Answer (score 1):

if you are on zsh then its just

```
vim **/foo.txt
```

or you can just enter vim and do the following from *within* vim:

```
:e **/foo.txt<ENTER>
```